# Custom tooltips for Wpf Devexpress controls

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have created a custom tooltip that is shown for WPF controls, but not for DevExpress WPF controls and I don't know why.

To add the tooltip I do something like this:

```
   <Button.ToolTip>
      <cc:TooltipControl Title="Test title" Text="Some text to show in tooltip"
                  ImageType="Information">                                
      </cc:TooltipControl>
   </Button.ToolTip>
```

My custom control inherits from the Tooltip control and has some properties that I added like *Title*, *Text* and *ImageType*. For the controls that don't belong to devexpress, my tooltip is shown but not for DevExpress controls.

What do I need to do in order to make the DevExpress controls show my tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the version for devexpress controls that I was using had a bug regarding the edit controls. I got a newer version and now it works, they fixed the bug.